# JavaScript: Stable method of updating connected clients variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have just stepped into the world of Web Development, and I am developing a small browser game that simply allows connected users to take control of an object (a triangle currently!), and simply move around the screen area.

Currently, I store the clients co-ordinate position in a MySQL database, and update that position using AJAX, roughly 30 times per second.

Other clients positions are also polled roughly 30 times per second.

My problem however, is that this seems to be causing an hour long IP lockout for the client, which I assume is automatically occurring on my Host's end. Would this perhaps be a normal default precautionary action? I was under the impression that 30 AJAX polls in a second was not a particularly stressful amount, however as I mentioned this is a new field for me. I'm fearful I've created some miniscule DOS attack!

If so, I would be grateful if someone with experience in this matter could point me to a more efficient method of handling the kind of interactivity I have described. This is all leading up to a six-month project I will be working on alone for my final year University project, so I'm more than happy to put the extra hours in to learn a better solution.

Comment: what is the platform on the server side? you may want to consider using websockets https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets

Comment: The host runs a Linux platform, which is about as much information I can give for the next 30 minutes due to another lockout. I have looked into WebSockets, however I understand that on its own it cannot connect with MySQL? Unless I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is known as "hybrid-polling". Basically you have a long running method server side which is running an "infinite" loop which runs once every 33ms (30 times per second). This loop will shoot data out to a part of your front end if the data has changed. When the data gets to be too large in the buffer for the method to handle, the method exits. The whole time your client is polling to see if new data was written. If the method exits, the client must restart the method. This is a hybrid approach, where the client polling is only checking client side data, except when the method exits, in which case the client must poll again to restart the server method, which then runs once every 33ms and pushes data out to the client.

Comment: I see a lot of articles talking about running things server side, but not a great deal of detail about how to achieve this. What do we mean specifically? My domain and server are hosted through a separate company. What kind of tool would I need to deploy server-side? My host is XILO.

Also, would this data benefit from landing in some kind of cache on my domain's web-disk?

I'm vaguely coming to understand the methods proposed to me, I just need to get my feet wet and try out an example. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @LBHoward - Do you have any control at all to the code server side? If not then you are stuck just polling client side and you will lock the server if you overload it. If you can affect server side code, then you would be using a while loop that ran until some buffer size was filled where the buffer size was related to the response that was being written to the client.

Comment: I don't believe I have any access to the server code. I access my administration via a browser based cPanel X. And access MySQL through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @LBHoward - cPanel comes with php support which would be your server side code.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense to me. What we be a sensible first step in writing server-side code (unrelated to the task), to gain some experience and understanding? And how might I tell that said code is working from the client?

Comment: @LBHoward - Look into making a "master page" that ensures all of the pages on your site share the same layout. This will help you see how a single piece of code can perpetuate itself through all of your content. Once you do that, you can move on to something more complex, perhaps file upload, chat, or a more advanced approach. There are a lot of nice php guides out there. Perhaps just "Hello World" would do best for a first step. Insert cliche...one step at at time, rome wasn't built overnight, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look up Comet (compatible with older browsers but not as efficient as possible), BOSH, or Web Sockets (ideal but not compatible with older browsers) for other approaches.